# TypeError: $source.offset is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a tree structure where the elements can be dragged and dropped into another element. My objective is when a element or node from a tree is dragged and dropped to the external element I want a line to be drawn from the element of the tree to the external location.

I have the code separate for dragging and dropping. I tried to integrate the code into my tree structure and getting this error. I did see similar errors but could not get an exact idea about what exactly the error is. Here is the code that is giving me the error.

```
end: function(item, hover, placeholder, helper) {
    if (placeholder.parent().length) {
    var tree = $('#tree1').aciTree('api');
    if (tree.isItem(item)) {
        var id = tree.getId(item);
        var label = tree.getLabel(item);
        if (this._instance.jQuery.hasClass('any')) {
            this._instance.jQuery.find('li:not(.aciSortablePlaceholder)').remove();
        }
        var item = $('<li id="item-' + id + '">' + label + '</li>');
        var sourceId = id;
        var destinationId = sourceId;
        drawLine(sourceId, destinationId);
        //This is how the function is called
        placeholder.after(item).detach();
     } 
        else {
            placeholder.detach();
     }
}
helper.detach();
}});

function drawLine(eTarget, eSource) {
    setTimeout(function () {
    var $source = eSource;
    var $target = eTarget;
    var originX = $source.offset().left + $source.width() + 20 + 4;
    // In the $source.offset() I am getting the error.
    var originY = $source.offset().top + (($source.height() + 20 + 4) / 2);

    var endingX = $target.offset().left;
    var endingY = $target.offset().top + (($target.height() + 20 + 4) / 2);

    var space = 20;
    var color = "black";

    var a = "M" + originX + " " + originY + " L" + (originX + space) + " " + originY; // beginning
    var b = "M" + (originX + space) + " " + originY + " L" + (endingX - space) + " " + endingY; // diagonal line
    var c = "M" + (endingX - space) + " " + endingY + " L" + endingX + " " + endingY; // ending
    var all = a + " " + b + " " + c;

    console.log("New Line ----------------------------");
    console.log("originX: " + originX + " | originY: " + originY + " | endingX: " + endingX + " | endingY: " + endingY + " | space: " + space + " | color: " + color );            
    console.log(all); 

    myLines[myLines.length] = svg
    .path(all)
    .attr({
         "stroke": color,
         "stroke-width": 1,
         "stroke-dasharray": "-"
     });
 }, 1000);
```

PS: I am using firefox. The eTarget and eSource and getting the values as supplied.

Comment: `var $source = eSource;` So what is `eSource`, i guess not a jQuery object?!  If it is a DOM node, wrap it in jQuery: `var $source = $(eSource);`

Comment: You need to show the calling code. If the parameters are not jQuery objects it will fail.

Comment: Ok cool, will edit the question and show how the it's called. I've just started seeing jQuery a week back, so it's kinda confusing all the way around.. :(

Comment: Hey @Vinnie, you should reproduce your issue on http://jsbin.com , update the question with a link and report back in comments.

Comment: Hey @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov I'm not sure I can put it in jsbin. I have like 10 css files which support and more than 10 javascript custom extensions just to make the page functional.

Comment: Don't reproduce the whole page. Create a *minimal* demonstration of the problem.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve_)